# Creating bundle products with fixed items in the bundle

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, bundled-product

I am trying to create a product bundle which contains 6 child products. 3 of these child products are fixed and must be included in the bundle. Each of the other 3 child products has different models and customer can choose which model he wants.

Is this possible with Magento?

**Why I can not use bundle products**

It is not possible to add fixed products. In addition user can change the qty (the qty of each item is fixed, only model can be chosen)

**Why I can not use configurable products**

If each of 3 child products has 2 models, I need to define 8 products. But I actually have 6 products. this causes problem in managing stock.

Is it possible to create such products in Magento?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### Why I can not use bundle products
>
> It is not possible to add fixed products. In addition user can change
> the qty (the qty of each item is fixed, only model can be chosen)

Good news: That's not true. You can add fixed products as well as selectable products with fixed qty.

For the fixed items, create one option each, as follows:

- **Type:** Drop-down
- **Is Required:** Yes
- One Selection

  - **Default Qty:** 1
  - **User Defined Qty:** No

For the other items, create one option each as follows:

- **Type:** Drop-down
- **Is Required:** Yes
- Multiple Selections for the different models:

  - **Default Qty:** 1
  - **User Defined Qty:** No

Comment: how to achieve if a bundle has only two products at fixed quantity. user must buy two products with specified quantity. user should not change quantity

Comment: always the same two items? then create two options in the first way I described (with one selection and no user defined qty)